# Searching for keywords and creating links automatically in Python and Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, hyperlink

I am creating an information web application (in Django) that often uses some medical terms. The medical terms and their explanations are stored in a separate model/database. As of now, I am manually creating links to description pages for each medical term.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the code automatically search a page contents for medical terms, and automatically create links (or popovers) to their description pages. All the pages are dynamic, and the medical terms are stored in their own separate model. So far, the medical terms model does not have a relationship with any other models

Any thoughts if this can be done (maybe through JS or Python), and if so, how to go about it?

Comment: So you have a text field in a model that contains bunch of texts which there is some medical terms including in the text? if that's correct then i guess you can try this: search for your medical terms in the text field and replace them with a link. like: "Item X" to `<a href='/itemx'>Item X</a>`. and then use autoscape tag in your template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape

Comment: Thanks. What I am trying to do is to automatize the search and hyperlinking of the medical terms, that are all stored in a separate model. Manual hyperlinking is needlessly repetitive and messy, leaving a lot of room for human error.

Comment: Well, i don't think you have any option but to go for messy stuff here. I prefer to scan the text before saving it and make a relation for that row to the items on medical terms mode. then you will know which terms has been used in this text. and if you don't wan't to search and replace the text, you can add a JavaScript file to your template to that for you. those relations will help you to find those terms faster because you don't need to search for all of them but just the ones you know they've been used in the text. This is a cleaner way but browser will do it not your server so ...

Comment: Also you can make a template tag to replace those tags so you won't need the js codes and your server will handle it too. If you don't want you text to be filled with bunch of html <a> tags then go for option 2 or 3. if it's okay for you to have bunch of html codes in your text then the first option is the fastest.